# Adding a pointer in a vector of objects

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, stdvector

I am trying to grasp the pointers in C++ but I can't find the answer to these questions.

If I was to have an ArrayList in Java and I wanted to add new Objects to it in a loop I would do something like:

```
ArrayList<MyObject> list = new ArrayList<MyObject> ();

for (int i = 0; i < otherList.length; i++) {
    list.add(i, new MyObject(otherList.get(i)));
}
```

But let's say I wanted to do the same thing in C++ using vectors. I have found two methods:

```
vector<MyObject> vector;

for (auto i = otherVector.begin(); i != otherVector.end(); i++) {
    // do this
    vector[i - otherVector.begin()] = * new MyObject(*i);

    // or this
    MyObject newObj(*i);
    vector[i - otherVector.begin()] = newObj;
}
```

What is the difference between those 2 methods and if I use the second one, do I need to manually delete the pointers from the list? If I were to use the second method with smart pointers, would they be automatically deleted by the gc when the vector was not used anymore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first method creates a memory leak. There's no saving it.  Forget you ever heard of operator `new`.

> if I use the second one, do I need to manually delete the pointers from the list?

There are no pointers in the list.

The second would work, and it would clean up after itself when `vector`goes out of scope. But do not do that either.

```
vector<MyObject> vector;

for (auto i = otherVector.begin(); i != otherVector.end(); i++) {
    // do this
    vector[i - otherVector.begin()] = * new MyObject(*i); // No, no, no, no.

    // or this
    MyObject newObj(*i); 
    vector[i - otherVector.begin()] = newObj; // Please don't.
}
```

But here's one way it should be done. No loop. (And don't name things "vector".)

```
std::vector<my_object> vec(other_vector);
```

If you're really into the brevity thing, do this:

```
auto vec{other_vector};
```